# Querying big tables dynamically in Shiny

Tags: sql, r, shiny, datatable

I'm developing a Shiny application, where the key functionality is something like this:

```
data <- odbc::dbGetQuery(con,'select * from someTable')

ui <- fluidPage(
   DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(data)
   })
}
```

So -- query some table in a SQL database, save the data to the app memory, and then display it in a DT. The user can then filter the table using the built-in DT filters, download it, etc. This works well for smaller datasets, but for a table with e.g. 50 columns and some 100000 rows, doing the initial load of the app becomes slow.

Instead, I want to use some sort of incremental load of the data, inspired by the approach [here](https://github.com/rszymanski/table-contest) -- so, upon opening the app, we query the first e.g. 10 rows of the table, when the user clicks 'next', we query the next 10 using OFFSET, when the user uses a filter, we append that WHERE clause to the query, and so on. The user's selection in the app would dynamically determine the query being sent to the database.

I can do some of this by taking the same approach as in the link above, but there's some work involved in creating the dynamic query, setting up the filters, and so on. Has anyone tried doing something similar -- or maybe created a package for handling this? Any 'good practice' tips or alternative approaches? Basically, I don't care too much about the implementation, I would just like to display data from a large table without loading all of it at once.

Comment: There's nothing really fancy about the query. Do you know how to use SQL's `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`? Last I checked, `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0` works to get the first 10 entries, then `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10` for the next 10, etc. BTW, not all DBMSes support it in the same way, it would help to add a tag for your specific database. (I suggest removing [tag:paging], that specific tag has more connotations than are needed here.)

Comment: Maybe I just need to sit down and do it, then. :) I know how to get e.g. 10 rows at a time by using LIMIT and OFFSET. Is there a good way of searching through the table? I.e. the datatable container in the Shiny app has a search field that searches through the entire table, how would you use this search term in the query?

Comment: I don't know that there's a pre-baked solution within `DT` for a SQL-backed data source. Perhaps https://github.com/grahamrp/dtdatasources might be useful. In my opinion, though, 100k rows and 50 columns is not gargantuan, I'd think you bite the bullet once with the data load and rely on DT to do the pagination (I believe it defaults to [server-side processing](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html), so by default it should not be dumping all data through the wire to the client's browser).